# show sender message twice in the char toom socet.io+redis+mysql+laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, redis

I'm developing a real time chat application using sokcet.io,redis under the laravel framework used MySQL database connection for save the users hat messages.
so i develop this application ,but i have facing one trouble.

my problem is.
when i sent a message to the chat room.that message show in my (sender window) two times(database message and redis event message).

i trying to several  ways to solve this problem ,but i can't find still a proper solution for this.

if you can help me to solve this it's very valuable help to me.
below i post my coding part
(redis event+socket connection+message.html+redis controller)
Thank you.

RedisEvent :

```
  class RedisEvent implements ShouldBroadcast{

use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public $message ;
public function __construct(Message $message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    //return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');

    return ['chat'];
}

public function broadcastAs(){
    return 'message';
}}
```

Redis Controller

```
class RedisController extends Controller{   
public function index()
{
    $messages = Message::all();

    return view('messages',compact('messages'));    }

  public function store(Request $request)
{

    $messages = Message::create($request->all());
    event(
        $e = new RedisEvent($messages)
    );
    return redirect()->back();
}}
```

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(6001);
console.log('Connected to port 6001');
io.on('error',function(socket){
console.log('error')
 });
  var Redis = require('ioredis');
  var redis = new Redis(1000);
   redis.psubscribe("*",function(error,count){
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
console.log('coonected with'+socket.id)
});
redis.on('pmessage',function(partner,channel,message){

message = JSON.parse(message);
socket.emit(channel+":"+message.event,message.data.message);
console.log('Sent')
 });
```

message.blade.php

```
<html>
   <body>

   <div id="data">
    @foreach($messages as $message)
    <p id="{{$message->id}}">database_<strong>{{$message->Sender}}</strong>: 
    {{$message->MessageTxt}}</p>
    @endforeach
 </div>

 <div>
      <form action="sendMessaged" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    Name: <input type="text" name="Sender">
    <br>
    <br>
    Content: <textarea name="MessageTxt" rows="5" style="width:100%">
    </textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
     </form>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js">
   </script>


     <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:6001');
         socket.on('chat:message',function(data){
          console.log(data)       

           if($('#'+data.id).length == 0){
            $('#data').append('<p>else__<strong>'+data.Sender+'</strong>: '+data.MessageTxt+'</p>')
        }
        else{

        }
    });     

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your RedisController change

```
event(
    $e = new RedisEvent($messages)
);
```

To:

```
broadcast(new RedisEvent($messages))->toOthers();
```

That way it excludes the sender from receiving the broadcasting of the message you are sending.

Read more on broadcasting in [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#only-to-others)

Comment: It may not  work because he has a nodejs proxy server in between